# Architecture: Storing all properties as JsonProperty in NDB?

Tags: database-design, nosql, google-app-engine

I am storing the data for my app in Google's NDB, but am confused as to what architecture to use. The app data is mostly text based, but has some non-text properties like `DateTimeProperty`, `FloatProperty` and one or two `BooleanProperty`'s.

I could store each property correctly (e.g. a `datetime` is stored as a `DateTimeProperty`), or I could already package all the data up as a JSON object and store it as a `JsonProperty`.

Storing everything as a `JsonProperty` gives the benefit of taking up less space (there's a `compress` flag that causes the content to be gzipped), but taking this approach makes it harder to search the database with `query()`.

Which approach is better to take?

Comment: can you give us some more input on what kind of app this will be as that will play a major role in what kind of architecture might work

Comment: @Maru I updated the question with types of data that need to be stored.

Comment: What matters isn't the type of data you're storing, it's how you want to retrieve it. If you can get away with retrieving entities by key only, then the JSON approach would work fine. If you need any sort of query-ability, you're hosed. I think that's what @Maru was asking for. Can you update your question with that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with using regular data types instead of serialising it to JSON then storing that instead as that is the most natural way to go about it plus you can index it.

Storing JSON objects have its uses too, especially if you want to make quick canned responses or if the one processing your data can readily read JSON(i.e. nodejs and its ilk) and the need to query this field doesn't exist(JSONProperty is stored as a blob, good luck indexing that)